# Spring boot embedded tomcat listening but not responding

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

When spring boot application is started with command "mvn spring-boot:run", tomcat server start listening at port 8080.

[image]

But when we access http://localhost:8080/index.html from browser tomcat will **NOT** respond. 
[image]

Below is the POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.des</groupId>
    <artifactId>trackerapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>trackerapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <version.commons-io>2.4</version.commons-io>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.90</tomcat.version>
        <start-class>com.test.des.trackerapp.trackerappApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${version.commons-io}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--WebJars -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.h2database</groupId> <artifactId>h2</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The starter class is shown below.

```
package com.test.des.trackerapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.des.trackerapp.repositories")
public class trackerappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(trackerappApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(trackerappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The folder structure for static content are shown below.

[image]

Can anyone help me to find what is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: is there any Controller class?

Comment: @ruhul controller class is there but I am checking for static content for testing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. Its with `server.contextPath` property in application.properties. 
It was set to `server.contextPath=/trackerappApplication`, changing this property to `server.contextPath=/` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat is working as expected because you get a HTTP staus code 404  (Not Found).

But you don't have any static content or RestController that returns any content.

So you could go ahead and add a index.html to src/main/resources/static or add a RestController with path "/" and then you will see output.

Comment: Simon, I have updated the question showing the folder structure for static content.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I have found the issue.